# <ul> element not taking full content width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, html-lists

I am making a navigation bar with unordered list. I am using flexbox.

Here is the code:

```css
/* navbar */

.top-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4%;
}

.top-nav-list {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* I have to change the grow & basis to get my desired result */
}

.top-nav-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2%;
  /* This padding has no effect on the full width of ul element */
}

.watch-link {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="top-navbar">
    <div class="nav-logo">Title</div>
    <ul class="top-nav-list">
      <!-- This is the problem element -->
      <li>Browse</li>
      <li><a href="">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TV</a></li>
      <li>Search Bar</li>
      <li>Expand</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="watch-link"><button class="watch-btn">Watchlist</button></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

There are 3 flex items in the container. One of which is the unordered list. The `ul` is not taking its full content width even though there is available space in the flex container. It's breaking into two lines. I can set the `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` to take more available space.

**But shouldn't it take the full content width by default?**
All the list items are inline block, still the last item is breaking into next line. `width:fit-content` also doesn't work. And the `padding` has no effect on the width. It just makes more items to go into 2nd line.

*I am also using sanitize css to normalize browser default styles.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the explanation for breaking lines. It was this line:

```
padding: 0 2%;  /*This padding has no effect on the full width of ul element */
```

I was making the child's (`list-item`) padding equal to a percentage of the parent's (`ul`) width. But the width is not defined yet. A parent's width is defined by the user or by its content. So, I was using a variable that doesn't exist yet. **This is also why the padding had no effect on the final width.**

So, as the browser can't set the padding without knowing the parent's width, it first calculates total width of `ul` based on all the children's content width without the padding. Then, after setting the width of `ul` without the padding, it gives `2%` padding to each children. But, as there is no extra space/width available in the `ul`, the line wraps/breaks, or overflows if we use `white-space: nowrap`

If we use any other padding units like `px`, `em` or `vw` , it works because the **children's width doesn't depend on parent's width which is not defined by the user.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `li` items breaks within `ul` element. So use `white-space:nowrap;` in your CSS:

```
.top-nav-list {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

An example:

```css
/* navbar */

.top-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4%;
}

.top-nav-list {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  /* I have to change the grow & basis to get my desired result */
}

.top-nav-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2%;  
}

.watch-link {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="top-navbar">
    <div class="nav-logo">Title</div>
    <ul class="top-nav-list">
      <!-- This is the problem element -->
      <li>Browse</li>
      <li><a href="">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TV</a></li>
      <li>Search Bar</li>
      <li>Expand</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="watch-link"><button class="watch-btn">Watchlist</button></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I know setting it to `grow: 1` will make it take all the available space. But my question is why the last list-item is breaking into 2nd line? Shouldn't it take at-least its content-width without setting it to grow? As all the list-items are inline-block.

Comment: @Md.ArefinRabbiEmon could you show in fiiddle where it breaks into the second line? It can break to next line as it is inline element when there is no available space at the right side.

Comment: I have edited my post to add a snippet now. Please see it. This breaking happens no matter how much space is available at the right side.

Comment: @Md.ArefinRabbiEmon please, see my updated answer

Comment: "It shrinks to its minimum size to fit the container" - shouldn't the minimum size be equal to its content-width as it doesn't need to shrink in this case to fit the container? I have tried deleting the `a` element and set `flex: 0 0 auto`. Still, the same result.

Comment: @Md.ArefinRabbiEmon please, see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. They solved my problem but I still didn't understand the root cause. I think I got the actual explanation why it was breaking lines. The problem was in the line `padding: 0 2%`. I have added my own answer now.